# Boxplots for grouped dataframe

Tags: python, boxplot

In a python script I have a pd's describe() output, called `df` looks like the following. The output has two index --`Class` and `EL_base`.

I want to make individual boxplot for each class. How can I do it?

```
                    count  mean   std   min    25%  50%    75%    max    
    Class  EL_base 
     PC1     0       8   247.04  8.16 236.90 244.15 245.17 247.71 265.41
             1       8   243.25  2.96 237.22 242.57 243.84 244.49 247.29
     PC2     0       8   243.25  2.96 237.22 242.57 243.84 244.49 247.29
             1       8   518.96  6.35 507.27 515.38 519.72 523.65 526.25
             2       8   519.52  2.84 513.77 518.17 520.50 521.46 522.39
```

Comment: Is this a generic question or are you limited to a particular environment & set of tools (eg. specific programming language, libraries, ...)?

Comment: This is python related boxplot question.

Comment: Boxplots typically take the full table as input, not the describe() output, e.g. seaborn.boxplot. Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864458/stacked-bar-plots-from-list-of-dataframes-with-groupby-command/58864810#58864810) question for how to generate subplots from groupby.

Comment: or easier: [pandas.DataFrame.boxplot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html)